# Why doesn't the split() function in Powershell match the whole given String?

Tags: string, powershell, split

I wonder why Powershell's `.split()` <s>function</s> method isn't giving me the expected result.
Actually I want to split a given String at the occurence of `CC=` but the function seems to split my String at every occurence of `C` and `=`.

For example:

```
$var = "randomStinng,XX=someContent,CC=moreCotent,CC=end"
$var.Split("CC=")

randomStinng,XX
some
ontent,


more
otent,


end
```

I try to avoid using `-split` since I with `split()` expressions like `$var.Split("CC=")[3]` are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-split` operator uses regular expressions, whilst the `.Split()` method does not. Does the following work for you?

```
$var = "randomStinng,XX=someContent,CC=moreCotent,CC=end"
$var -split "CC="
```

**Edit:**

You can use `-split` like you want it too:

```
($var -split "CC=")[3]
```

Comment: Ah I really didn't come up with your second idea. Of course this works!

Comment: @LotPings fixed

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, you're certainly right!

Comment: Alternativ you can use : [regex]::Split($var,"CC=")